# How can I add multiple data to <li>?

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
function addUserDataToDom(data) {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  const userList = document.getElementById('user-list')
  const userName = data.items[0].login
  const id = data.items[0].id
  const avatarUrl = data.items[0].avatar_url
  li.innerHTML = userName
}
```

I have to add my id and avatarUrl to <li> and append to the page? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add any element to another one with **.appendChild( childElement )**. So if you want to add the "li" to the body of your document you can do this:

```js
document.body.appendChild( li )
```

So, in order to achieve what you asked, you should make this:

```js
function addUserDataToDom(data) {

    const li = document.createElement('li')
    const userList = document.getElementById('user-list')
    const userName = data.items[0].login
    const id = data.items[0].id
    const avatarUrl = data.items[0].avatar_url

    // Create p elements to add your user data
    const pUserName = document.createElement("p")
    const pId = document.createElement("p")
    const pAvatrUrl = document.createElement("p")
    
    pUserName.innerText = userName
    pId.innerText = id
    pAvatrUrl.innerText = avatarUrl

    li.appendChild( pUserName )
    li.appendChild( pId )
    li.appendChild( pAvatrUrl )

}
```

As you can see, all the data was added as innerText inside the **p** element.
Finally you have to append those **p** elements we created earlier inside your **li** element.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have already created an element <li> and I added inner HTML into it to equal my user name, so now I have to add other data ( as id of that user name and URL) ? Thanks

Comment: @Angela you want to add the data inside de element or just set the data whit **setAttribute**?. In other words, where you want to add the data, inside the li element?

Comment: inside the <li>
 li.innerHTML = userName  this is how I made my username to show up , but under that I have to add "username's id and Url " which I created  above in my function

Comment: Okay, so the question is how to add multiple elements inside your li right?

Comment: I guess you're right. Sorry for confusion

Comment: No problema @Angela, i edited the answer.